# Probability of person having A if person also owns B

Tags: probability

So I'm in Honors Geometry and this question was in our homework last night, but when my teacher explained it, I still couldn't understand why I was wrong.

> At Bell High School, $43\%$ of the students own a CD player and $28\%$ own a CD player and an MP3 player. What is the probability that a student owns an MP3 player if he or she also owns a CD player?

Why isn't the answer simply $28\%$? I think it could be the wording of the problem that confuses me, but to me it seems that the question simply states the answer inside of it.

Answer (score 4):

Imagine there are 100 students.  Of them 43 own a CD player.  Out of those, 28 own both a CD player and an MP3 player.  The question asks the chance that if you choose a random student out of the 43 that own a CD player, what is the chance that s/he also owns an MP3 player.  Clearly that is higher than $28\%$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let's say Bell is small and only has 100 students.  So 42 students have a CD player and 28 students have a CD player *and* MP3 player.  Pick one student.  All you know about him is that he owns a CD player.  That means he is one of 42 students.  To also own an MP3 player, he would also have to be part of a subset of 28 students.  So, he owns a CD player and the probability that he also owns an MP3 player is .... ?

Answer (score 0):

If there are $n$ students then $\dfrac{43}{100}n$ own a CD player and of these $\dfrac{28}{100}n$ own an MP3 player too.

So the proportion of CD player owners who also own an MP3 player is   $\dfrac{\frac{28}{100}n}{\frac{43}{100}n}=\dfrac{28}{43}$.